# DHCP Should not be installed on a Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003

Why DHCP should not be installed on a domain controller?> What are drawbacks of it? What problems can be caused if I installed it on DC?

Comment: Who says it shouldn't?

Answer (score 5):

This is not conventional wisdom. Perhaps you're confusing RRAS with DHCP? That's problematic because it multihomes the DC. DHCP on DCs is extremely common.

Answer (score 1):

> In addition, the DHCP Server service should not be placed on an Active
>   Directory domain  controller if this can be avoided. The reason for
>   this is because this changes security related to  service locator
>   (SRV) records, which domain controllers are responsible for
>   publishing. SRV  records detail the location of domain controller s,
>   Kerberos servers, and other servers, and the  changes to the security
>   of these records when you install DHCP means that the records could 
>   be altered by any client on the network. The reason this happens is
>   because DHCP servers must be able to update client records 
>   dynamically if a client’s IP address changes. Because of this, they
>   are made members of the  DNSUpdateProxy group, and members of this
>   group do not have any security applied to  objects they create in the
>   DNS database. If you can’t avoid placing DHCP on a domain con-
>   troller, it is recommended that you remove the DHCP server from the
>   DNSUpdateProxy  group. This should avoid the security problem outlined
>   here, but will also prevent the DHCP  server from dynamically updating
>   client records in DNS when the client IP addresses change.

Source: "Windows Server 2003 Inside Out"

Comment: That is a rather large security flaw in the OS.

Comment: This doens't make sense to me: Yes, the DHCP server can update ANY DNS record including the SRV records, but why does that allow that ANY client to alter those records ? It is still the trusted server that does the altering with data supplied by it's own service: The data doesn't come from the client.

Comment: If secure updates dynamic updates are enabled the DNSUpdateProxy group isn't necessary and this is not enabled. This is a very specific corner case which can be mitigated by removing the DC from DNSUpateProxy group if it is even there in the first place. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961412.aspx